# Why the TweetVolume is null when I fetch the Top Trends?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, tweetinvi

I'm fetching the top trends of twitter using `tweetinvi`, Some of the trends have the `tweet_volume` value null, Am I doing anything wrong? Why its null?

```
List<Tweet> topTrends = new List<Tweet>();

ITwitterCredentials creds = new TwitterCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
Auth.SetCredentials(creds);

var trends = Trends.GetTrendsAt(23424977);

for (int i = 0; i < trends.Trends.Count(); i++)
{
    Tweet tweet = new Tweet
    {
        Name = trends.Trends[i].Name,
        Volume = trends.Trends[i].TweetVolume,
        Url = trends.Trends[i].URL,
        Count = trends.Trends[i].PromotedContent
    };
    trendList.Add(tweet);
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, it's just that not all trends have volumes attached to them. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place

Comment: @AndyPiper Thanks a lot :)